# Default value for a $PROPERTY in Gradle

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

How can I specify a default value for this simple `build.gradle` script:

```
println "Hello $build_version"
```

So that I don't get the error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'hello_gradle'.
> Could not find property '$build_version' on root project 'hello_gradle'.
```

I tried some of the operators, checking for nulls etc, but I think just the reference to the property makes it fail. I could fix that by always providing the property, but that's less than ideal.

```
gradle -Pbuild_version=World
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
if (!project.hasProperty("build_version")) {
    ext.build_version = "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a `${property:"default value"}` syntax or am I mixing this up with Spring configuration? Your example is missing the closing parantheses in the if statement btw.

Comment: Groovy's elvis operator (`${property ?: "default value"}`) won't work here because a missing property won't return `null` but cause the error shown in the original post. Added the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Just remember when you access the property to use just `${build_version}` and not `${ext.build_version}`

Comment: would be nice if Gradle would have a `project.getPropertyOrDefault(name)`

Answer (score 24):

This checks if the property exists and assigns a default value if not:

```
def build_version=project.properties['build_version'] ?: "nokey"
```

Comment: I've found this is roughly 3 times as slow as: `def build_version = project.hasProperty('build_version') ? project.property('build_version') : 'nokey'`

Answer (score 6):

Starting from Gradle 2.13:

```
ext.buildVersion = project.findProperty('build_version') ?: '1.0'
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
def AWS_ACCESS_KEY="nokey"
def AWS_SECRET_KEY="nokey"

if (project.hasProperty("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")) {
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY=project.get("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
}
if (project.hasProperty("AWS_SECRET_KEY")) {
    AWS_SECRET_KEY=project.get("AWS_SECRET_KEY")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make it short and nice:

```
ext.buildVersion = project.getProperties().getOrDefault("build_version", "1.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding this to my build.gradle:

```
String propValue(String propName, String defValue) {
    (project.hasProperty(propName) && project.getProperty(propName)) ? project.getProperty(propName) : defValue
}
```

then use when needed `propValue('build_version', 'nokey')`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?:

```
println "Hello ${project.getProperty('build_version', 'default_string_value')}"
```

Comment: `Could not find method getProperty()`

Comment: Sorry, a syntax error. I meant: println "Hello ${project.getProperty('build_version') ?: 'default_string_value'}"

Comment: `project.getProperty` throws an error if it's undefined. `project[property]` does not.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner using ternary operator:

`println "Hello ${project.hasProperty('build_version') ? getProperty('build_version') : 'World'}"`

`gradle <your_task> -Pbuild_version=SomethingElse`

Comment: Note that's not specifying a default value to a property. Thanks.